# Stellar horizon server - still 'waiting for ingestion'

Tags: javascript-sdk

I am using the IONOS server and I created the Stellar horizon server
but I faced this issue:

```
INFO[2020-12-17T21:18:54.302Z] waiting for ingestion system catchup          pid=35554 service=ingest status="{false false 0 0}"
INFO[2020-12-17T21:18:56.302Z] waiting for ingestion system catchup          pid=35554 service=ingest status="{false false 0 0}"
INFO[2020-12-17T21:18:58.302Z] waiting for ingestion system catchup          pid=35554 service=ingest status="{false false 0 0}"
INFO[2020-12-17T21:19:04.302Z] waiting for ingestion system catchup          pid=35554 service=ingest status="{false false 0 0}"
```

It may be my firewall?
If you know about this, please give me the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is that increase your server storage size.

Comment: Thank you, the issue was solved :)

Comment: One question.
Would you please let me know how to exchange the currencies in stellar?

Comment: I think you can exchange the currencies by sending his address.
For example, if you want to exchange USD to EUR you can send your EUR to your same address.

Comment: Also, other way is that creating issur account on your anchor.

Comment: Thank you so much. one thing more
Is there the API to do bank transfer in anchor?
If so, how can I use it?

Comment: I think, there is not that.
So, I integrated bank api to stellar network.

Comment: Oh, I see
What bank API did you use? would you please recommend?